# 'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I installed mongoose with `npm i mongoose` it shows in the `package.jason` dependencies also but when I run the command `mongod` it shows the error `'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`
how to fix this error

Comment: I'm not familiar with `mongoose`, but the shown error means that `mongod` is not presented in your current folder or this path is not in the `PATH` env variable. 
To fix it, you should do either change your current folder on the folder with `mongod`,  add `mongod` into the PATH env variable or use the full `mongod.exe` path like: `>C:\mongo\bin\mongod.exe`

Comment: please resolve the question then